# How do I add a footer that only has a button and the footer spans the entire row?

Tags: asp.net

The closest I've been able to get is the following:

```
<asp:TemplateField FooterStyle-CssClass="PagerNavigationButtons">
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteReview" ImageUrl="~/DeleteReview.png" runat="server"/>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

This however will create a new blank field (and row) and put the button only at the bottom of that field.  I haven't had much luck finding something so obvious through Googling either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a css class that sets the width to 100%.

```
<style>
.wide { display: block; width: 100%; }
</style>

<asp:TemplateField FooterStyle-CssClass="PagerNavigationButtons">
<FooterTemplate>
<asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteReview" CssClass="wide" ImageUrl="~/DeleteReview.png" runat="server" />
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```